# Virtual function keyword

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, virtual

Is there any difference between declaring inherited virtual function in a child class **with** the "virtual" keyword **or not**, considering I want to call fun appropriate to my objects' type. Look at the comments.

```
#include <cstdio>
struct A{
    int a;
    A():a(5){}
    virtual int fun(){return a+1;}
};
struct B: public A{
    virtual int fun(){return a+5;} //I put virtual here
//  int fun(){return a+5;} // Any difference if I put virtual before or not?
};
int main(){
    B obj;
    printf("%d\n", static_cast<A>(obj).fun()); // A::fun() called. Why?
    printf("%d\n", static_cast<A&>(obj).fun()); // B::fun() called. As expected
    printf("%d\n", static_cast<A*>(&obj)->fun()); // B::fun() called. As expected
    printf("%d\n", static_cast<A>(B()).fun()); // A::fun() again. Why?
//  printf("%d\n", static_cast<A&>(B()).fun()); //invalid_cast error. Why? 
    printf("%d\n", static_cast<A*>(&B())->fun()); //It works! B::fun() call
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That very last `&B()` is a compiler extension, it is not valid C++. Try to find the settings to put your compiler in conformant mode.

Comment: @Luc Compiler warned me I took address of temporary, I consider it is ok

Comment: What you consider ok or not is irrelevant to what is valid C++ :) Note that if the compiler did warn you, then it *is* a conforming compiler. You can disregard my previous comment (and I strongly suggest that you write valid C++).

Comment: You can take non cost reference to a temporary. The second to last can be `printf("%d\n", static_cast<A const &>(B()).fun()); /* if you make fun() const */`

Comment: @Luc I thought if something is placed in memory I can/should use it :D

Comment: @Martin `const_cast<A&>(static_cast<const A&>(B())).fun()` works aswell.

Comment: @all Your compiler is one of the tools to know what you can or cannot do. You don't have to second guess: if there is a warning and you don't know why, then you probably can't do that.

Comment: @all: Yes. There are many ways to abuse the language. But const_cast is one of those code smell things that I would not recommend using. When I see it somebodies code I am pretty sure I will find some nasty smelly code hiding around the corner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overriding functions in derived classes are implicitly declared "virtual" if the corresponding function in the base class is virtual. Just make sure you got the exact same signature, or you might inadvertently hide the original function and declare a new one!

In C++0x, feel free to make liberal use of the `override` specifier.

Your two "Why?" questions are because of *slicing*; you're making new, copy-sliced objects of type `A`. Note that in `B x; static_cast<A>(x);` the cast is the same as saying `A(x)`.

Comment: Thanks, take a look at two last printfs, why last is ok(take pointer and static_cast), but previous cast is invalid(cast to reference).

Comment: You can't make a non-const reference to a temporary. Cast to const reference instead.

Comment: `const_cast<A&>(static_cast<const A&>(B())).fun()` works. Is there any other way to call non-const function of const object?

Comment: @all With C++0x you can do `to_value(B()).fun()`, assuming `template<typename T> T& to_lvalue(T&& t) { return t; }`.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping the **virtual** key word before the overridden member function in the derived class is optional. Run-time polymorphism works only for pointers or references.